# Compact representation of this recursive sum

Tags: summation, compactness, recursion

I have a vector **x** and a function that sums the elements of **x** like so:

$$f(1) = x_1$$
$$f(2) = x_1 + \sum_{i=1}^2 x_i$$
$$f(3) = x_1 + \sum_{i=1}^2 x_i + \sum_{j=1}^3 x_j$$
$$f(4) = x_1 + \sum_{i=1}^2 x_i + \sum_{j=1}^3 x_j + \sum_{k=1}^4 x_k$$

...and so on. How might I represent this function more compactly, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(n) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{i} x_j = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} (n-i+1)x_i$

Comment: Very elegant! What is the name for this method?

Comment: I don't think there's a name.

Comment: @user1684046 This is basically just factoring, using the distributive property.

Comment: @user1684046 The second part is called changing the order of summation.

Answer (score 0):

Since there was the "recursion" tag in your question, here is a recursive solution:

$ f (0) = 0$

$f (n+1) = f (n) + \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} x_i$